# Unable to read different kind of shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, geometry, java, geotools, oracle-spatial

I have written the Java code to read the shapefile and insert it into the table. But the way I have written code it will accept only a multistring .shp file. It fails for other shapefile geometry types, e.g. polygon.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String fileUploaded(Model model, @Validated File file,
            BindingResult result) throws IOException, SchemaException {
        System.out.println("File Name is given below");
        System.out.println("File Name is " +file.getFile().getOriginalFilename());
        String returnVal = "successFile";
        String fileLoc="D:\\SpringMVCFileUpload\\springexample\\src\\upload\\"+file.getFile().getOriginalFilename();
        java.io.File newFile = new java.io.File(fileLoc);

        // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!newFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
          newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();  
        }
        FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getFile().getBytes(), newFile);

        DataStore fileDataStore=FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(newFile);
        String typeName=fileDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

        SimpleFeatureCollection collection = fileDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName).getFeatures();

        SimpleFeatureIterator iterator=collection.features();

        java.util.Map params = new java.util.HashMap();
        params.put( "dbtype", "Oracle");
        params.put( "host", "localhost");
        params.put( "port", 1521);
       // params.put( "schema", "PUBLIC");
        params.put( "database", "orcl");
        params.put( "user", "mdsys");
        params.put( "passwd", "mdsys");
        DataStore dataStore=DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);

        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource= dataStore.getFeatureSource("COAST_TEST");


        final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("COAST_TEST",
                "feature_id:Integer,GEOMETRY:MultiLineString,SCALERANK:Integer"
        );
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
        int i=0;
        ListFeatureCollection dbCollection=new ListFeatureCollection(TYPE);
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            SimpleFeature feature=iterator.next();
            featureBuilder.add(i++);
            featureBuilder.add(feature.getAttribute("the_geom"));
            featureBuilder.add(feature.getAttribute("scalerank"));
            SimpleFeature dbFeature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
            dbCollection.add(dbFeature);

        }

    Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");
        if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
            SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;
            featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
            try {
                featureStore.addFeatures(dbCollection);
                transaction.commit();

            } catch (Exception problem) {
                problem.printStackTrace();
                transaction.rollback();

            } finally {
                transaction.close();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(typeName + " des not support read/write access");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        if (result.hasErrors()) {
        //  System.out.println("File Name is given below");
            returnVal = "file";
        } else {            
            MultipartFile multipartFile = file.getFile();   
        //  System.out.println("File Name is given below");
            returnVal = "successFile";
            }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

In the above code you will see that Simplefeaturetype object TYPE for table "COAST_TEST" geometry field accepts only multistring. How do I let that object have different type for geometry field based on the kind of shapefile I am uploading?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would ask the features to give you their schema using:

```
SimpleFeatureType schema = collection.getSchema();
```

You can then use that to generate the Oracle schema to write the data into.

Comment: Good answer by iant, but I just want to add a caveat: mixing geometry types in the same field is frowned upon. There are a lot of applications that have a hard time dealing with that.

Comment: I was assuming/hoping he would put each shapefile into a different table as there is no checking to make sure the attributes are the same